# Compiling numpy for windows (Python 2.7.7)

Tags: c++, python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to run numpy (any version) on a embedded interpreter compiled with Visual Studio 2008. If I compile the code in release mode I have no problem executing the whole project, my problem arises when I try to build on debug mode; if I do this all I get is error messages while trying to import numpy on python code.

I think might be related to the fact that numpy does not contain debug symbols. How can I solve this?

Any suggestions or ideas?

Should I try to compile from scratch numpy? If so, can you provide some guidance?

Comment: don't know about windows but under linux you need a special debug build of python (configure --enable-debug) and use that to build numpy. Then you have debug symbols and the python debug runtime.